# Gradle: set transitive = false option for multiple modules

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Working with `Gradle 2.13` and with a project with multiple modules

I could have the following:

```
project(':module-main') {
    description 'Main'
    dependencies {     
       compile project(':module-config')
       ['spring-context'].each { compile "org.springframework:$it:$springFrameworkVersion" }
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the *transitive dependencies* are referenced, according with my research I can avoid that using `transitive = false` how for example:

```
project(':module-main') {
        description 'Main'
        dependencies {     
           compile (project(':module-config')){
               transitive = false
           }
           ['spring-context'].each { compile "org.springframework:$it:$springFrameworkVersion" }
        }
    }
```

Until here I am ok with this, but if a module depends on *many other* modules, I want avoid the following (is verbose)

```
project(':module-main') {
        description 'Main'
        dependencies {     
           compile (project(':module-config')){
               transitive = false
           }
           compile (project(':module-abc')){
               transitive = false
           }
           compile (project(':module-xyz')){
               transitive = false
           }
           ['spring-context'].each { compile "org.springframework:$it:$springFrameworkVersion" }
        }
    }
```

How you can see I am using many times the `transitive = false` for each
`compile project(':module-xyz')`. And it just for one module, I could have other modules with the same situation.

Is there a *global special configuration* where I can use `compile project(':module-xyz')` and it automatically defaults to `transitive = false`? (it from the *global special configuration*)

I did a research, where I should use

```
configurations {
    compile {
            transitive false
    }
    testCompile {
            transitive false
    }
}
```

I have tried that in:

- root level
- within `all projects{}` section
- within `subprojects{}` section

and nothing, my unique way is setting `transitive = false` for each `compile project(':module-something')` within a module